# Defining quotient topolgy on mapping based on subbase of a topology and related question.

Tags: general-topology

For the following two questions:

> **1)** Let $X$ be the continuous, real-valued functions on the interval $[0,1]$. For $f\in X$ and $\epsilon > 0$, consider the sets
>   $$S_{f,\epsilon} =\{g\in X: |g(x)-f(x)|<\epsilon, \text{for all }  x\in [0,1]\}$$
>   Using these sets as a sub-basis, describe the resulting topology. 
>   **2)** Let $X$ be the continuous function on the unit interval $[0,1]$ equiqqed with the uniform topology as described in previous exercise.  Let $Y$ be the real numbers.  Let $T:X\rightarrow Y$ be defined by 
>   $$T(f)=\int^1_0 f(x) \, dx$$
>   What is the quotient topology induced on $Y$ by the mapping $T$?

I know for (1), it is most likely the uniform topology.  I am guessing it is so, because it has to do with continuity of functions independent of $\delta$.  I don't know how to show it partly because I don't know how to define the collection of subbasic open sets.  Do I define a finite intersection of open sets in terms of a particular $\epsilon$ and then take their collective union to form a topology. 
For (2), am I right to guess that it is the euclidean topology.  Because by definition of quotient topology,

> **Definition:**  Let $(X,U)$ be a topological space and let $Y$ be any set.  Suppose that $f:X\rightarrow Y$ is a surjective mapping.  Then the collection of subsets
>   $$\tau_f=\{{G\subset Y:f^{-1}(G) \text{ is open in } X\}}$$
>   is a topology on $Y$ called the quotient topology induced on $Y$ by $f$.  When $Y$ is endowed with such a quotient topology, then it is called a quotient space of $X$, and the inducing map $f$ is called a quotient map.

the collection $G\subset of Y$ has to form a topology where $(T\circ f)^{-1}(G)=(f^{-1}\circ T^{-1})(G)$ is open in $X$.  So the collection of open sets $G$ as inverse images of $T(f)$ are just open sets are each open intervals each containing the real value of $T(f)$.  Is that correct?  Thank you in advance

Comment: Rather than a basis for the topology on $X$, the sets mentioned in 1) describe a neighbourhood base for each $f \in X$; regardless, the topology in question is induced by the natural metric on $X$, itself induced by the natural norm given by $\lVert f \rVert =\mathrm{sup}\ \mathrm{Im}|f|$. As for 2), the quotient topology is indeed the standard one.

Comment: $2$ already gives away in its formulation that $1$ induces the uniform topology. Show that all subbasic sets are open in $\|.\|_\infty$ norm and vice versa. This is quite easy.

Comment: The Euclidean topology is *one* of the topologies on $Y$ that makes $T$ continuous. Is it the finest one that does?

Comment: @HennoBrandsma I wan to ask, does it matter if I use some other norm instead of the infinity norm.  Also, I think the Euclidean topology would have to be, unless there is another topology has is finer than the euclidean topology, finer compare to all other topologies with the exception of the indiscrete topology which I do not know about.